# `jest.mock` Not Mocking Utility Function That's Prompting For User Input

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

## Description

I am attempting to write a unit test to mock a function called `prompt_user` which waits for the user to input text for a text rpg I'm writing. The way I've put the test together is not resulting in the `prompt_user` function being replaced with the mock and I'm trying to understand why.

[For context this is the jest documentation I'm using to try to build this test](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials)

[For reference my attempts to create these unit tests can be seen here](https://github.com/Bogsworth/RPGWebsite/tree/UnitTestRoundTwo)

The test hangs forever on the call to `game.main_loop()` since it's waiting for user input that never happens.

## game.js.test

```js
import * as game from "./game.js"
import { user_prompt } from './shared_functions.js'

jest.mock('./shared_functions', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual( './shared_functions' );

  //Mock the default export and named export 'foo'
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    user_prompt: jest.fn( () => 'Name' ),
  };
});

test('should do a partial mock', () => { 
    game.main_loop()
    expect( gamestate.player.inventory ).toContain( ritual_dagger );
});
```

## game.js

```js
import * as util from "./shared_functions.js"

function main_loop( passed_gamestate ) {
    let gamestate = {}

    util.create_character( gamestate ); // This is where the test hangs
    game_loop( gamestate );
    end_game( gamestate );
}
```

## shared_functions.js

```js
import PromptSync from "prompt-sync"
const prompt = PromptSync()


function create_character( gamestate ) {
    print( `\n` )
    var NAME = user_prompt( 'What is your name? ' );
    let character = new Player_Class( NAME, 4, 4, 4 )
    
    character.update_condition( "fresh", true )
    print( `Welcome ${character.playername}!` )

    gamestate.player = character
}

function user_prompt ( question ) {
    return prompt( question ) ;
}

export {
    create_character,
    user_prompt
}
```